# Which threshold does h2o.predict() use on new testing set?

Tags: r, h2o

I have read several threads on here in regards to h2o.predict() and h2o.performance() differences (as seen from link below).

[How to interpret the probabilities (p0, p1) of the result of h2o.predict()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304696/how-to-interpret-the-probabilities-p0-p1-of-the-result-of-h2o-predict)

Can someone tell me which threshold does h2o.predict() use? Is it `max f1`? If so, is it the threshold from training data, validation data, or cross validation?

I tried to use the validation threshold using `max f1` and `max f0point5` on the testing set (completely separate from training and validation data) but the predicted class from h2o.predict() and the class from using the threshold doesn't match completely.

The closest one I got is to use `max f0point5` threshold from training and apply it to testing set.

There is not much documentation on h2o.predict. Also, is there a best practice for threshold, i.e. mean threshold of validation and training, etc?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the specifics of how the prediction threshold is selected when a user runs `h2o.predict()` or `.predict()`:

1) if you train a model with only training data - the Max F1 threshold from the train data model metrics is used.

2) if you train a model with train and validation data - the Max F1 threshold from the validation data model metrics is used.

3) if you train a model with train data and set the nfold parameter - the Max F1 threshold from the train data model metrics is used.

4) if you train a model with the train data, validation data and set the nfold parameter -  the Max F1 threshold from the validation data model metrics is used.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown Lauren :).