# Threshold used at prediction

Tags: r, h2o

According to the H2O documentation, the threshold used at prediction is the max F1 threshold from train.
The performance function,

```
h2o.performance(model, newdata = test)
```

actually run the prediction on the test set in order to compute the confusion matrix.

Strangely I am getting different confusion matrix while predicting the same test set using :

```
h2o.predict(object, newdata=test).
```

It means that `h2o.performance()` is using a different threshold from `h2o.predict()`.
I am wondering how can i dictate the threshold upon prediction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2O is using max F1 threshold for both h2o.performance() and h2o.predict(). The difference is **what dataset** it will use to estimate the max F1 threshold.

---

*h2o.predict()* will use the threshold it selected during training. It uses different max F1 thresholds depending on how the model was trained. Basically:

- If you only have training data - the max F1 threshold comes from the train data model.
- If there is validation data during training - the max F1 threshold comes from the validation data model.

This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#prediction-threshold) and also on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587308/which-threshold-does-h2o-predict-use-on-new-testing-set). Depending on if you had validation data during training, you will see the max F1 threshold to be determined by your **training or validation** dataset.

*h2o.performance()* will take the model and newdata and calculate what threshold will give the highest F1 for the **new data**. In your case, **test** is being used to calculate max F1 threshold.